# Rails 4 Active Model Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a Contact Us form on my website using Active Model.

The problem I am having is errors messages are never returned.

I'm using a remote form.

routes:

```
 resource :front_contacts, only: :create, controller: :front_contact
```

controller:

```
 class FrontContactController < ApplicationController
   def create
     contact = FrontContact.new(params[:front_contact])
     @errors = contact.errors.size
   end
 end
```

front_contact:

```
 class FrontContact
   include ActiveModel::Model

   attr_accessor :name, :email, :message

   validates_presence_of :name, :message
   validates_format_of :email, with: /[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+(com|net|org|info|biz|me|edu|gov)/i
  end
```

js.erb:

```
  alert(<%= @errors %>);
```

The alert is always alerting zero.

Please advise.

Comment: I think if you used scaffold there would be muuuch more code in `create`, important code, you know ;)

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I could use a scaffold. The current system just sends off an email when contacted. I thought Active Model would be cool for the validations, but not saving the data.

Comment: Ah, dumb me! I didn't see it's active model. Anyway. YOu should have exactly the same features as in action operating on activeredord, this means new, save, and some action after successful/failed save.

Comment: I think you should call contact.valid? method to errors appear.

Comment: Yes. The new method doesn't run through the validations so as @gvalmon said you need to run .valid? To get it to check the validations. Especially if you are not calling .save.

Comment: Awesome. Calling valid? did the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails 4, there's the new inclusion of strong params that may be preventing your models from getting created.

Do you have something like the following anywhere in your controller?

```
params.require(:front_contact).permit!
```

I had the same problem as you when initially switching over to Rails 4, and was baffled because not permitting specific params doesn't throw an error message; the object just doesn't get created.

If you have a RailsCasts account, there's a really great video on how to deal with strong params [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/371-strong-parameters).